# How to make a proper Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to make regular expression so it matches only value as bellow, but I want to make it so you have to have at least one (i know it works with the "+" symbol) a-z letter, but I don't know where to put the "+" to make it work correctly. Any help on this?

```
.match(/^[0-9a-z]{3,10}$/i)
```

**Edit:**
It should match for string like "12a", but it shouldn't match for "123" cause it has to have at least one a-z in it.

```
if( ! ($Username.match(/^[0-9a-z]{3,10}$/i) && $Username.match(/[a-z]/i)) ) {
    return false;
}
```

**Edit:**
Thanks to Felix now the example code above works perfect.

Comment: It always helps with regex questions if you post a few strings that should match and a 1 or more should not match.

Comment: Good point, didn't think of it. Edited.

Comment: Some would deem “proper Javascript regex” to be oxymoronic. :)

Comment: @tchrist, what is "oxymoronic"?

Comment: It has to be `$Username.match(/[a-z]/i)`. `a-z` must be in a character class, otherwise it matches a-z literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean:

- Between 3 and 10 characters (inclusive)
- All letters or numbers
- At least one letter in any position

Then the simplest way to achieve this would be:

```
foo.match(/^[0-9a-z]{3,10}$/i) && foo.match(/[a-z]/i);
```

Comment: @subtenante — thanks for the catch, fixed. This is what comes of too much exposure to jQuery ;)

Comment: Wondering if doing to reg exp matches is more efficient than doing one, but a little bit complicated?

Comment: @Richards — assuming that such a regex exists (nobody has suggested one that meets the outlined conditions so far), then simple beats efficient until there is a real performance problem. "premature optimization is the root of all evil" — Donald Knuth

Comment: There is none, don't look for it farther. What Richards describes is neither right-linear nor left-linear. Ergo : it's not regular.

Comment: @daviddorward, actually I'm having trouble to get your example working.. Added code to first post.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in a single step. The expression you talk about is not regular. You have to make it in several steps. Just match with your current expression and combine to the match with a `/[a-z]/` expression.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the filtering, although you'll have to check the character count separately:

```
^[0-9a-z]*[a-z]+[0-9a-z]*$
```

Comment: That regex doesn't even compile.

Comment: This does not enforce one letter.

Comment: Now that the OP has clarified the post, I've updated my answer to (i think) solve it

Comment: This does not enforce 3 to 10 characters ;)

Comment: Well to my credit -- While one might infer that from the OP's regex attempt, neither his copy nor his examples specified it :)